# Log script at linux startup/shutdown

Tags: linux, shell, centos, symlink

I'm learning to use shell script on linux (I'm working on CentOS 6.7) and file system too. Now I'm creating a script that writes messages in a text file when the system is started up or shut down. I've placed the following in /etc/init.d:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# This is a test that send messages to a log
LOGPATH=/home/user/documents
now=$(date +'%T')

start() {
  echo "[$now] System startup" >> $LOGPATH/test.log
}

stop() {
    echo "[$now] System shutdown" >> $LOGPATH/test.log
}

status() {
    echo "[$now] Hi, you're checking status" >> $LOGPATH/test.log
}

case "$1" in
  start)
      start
      ;;
  stop)
      stop
      ;;
  restart)
      $0 stop
      $0 start
      ;;
  status)
      status
      ;;
  *)
      ## If no parameters are given, print which are avaiable.
      echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status}"
      exit 1
      ;;
esac
```

Then I created K symblinks in rc0 and rc6 for shutdown and reboot and S symblinks in rc5 (my default).

It worked on startup, but it didn't on shutdown. After rebooting a few times trying different things, I only have "[time] System startup", even giving a K01 priority to the script in rc0.

Why is not working on shutdown? Maybe Kill signal on reboot doesn't work like I think it works, but I'm just not sure.

Comment: Not a programming question really, is it?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is writing a `service`. As such you should not create those symlinks manually, instead you should use the `chkconfig` command to add your shell script as a new service.

There are special comment lines that you need to add at the top of your script for `chkconfig` to handle it correctly. Take a look at both the man pages for `chkconfig` and `service`.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a service, but I wanted to try if it can be done manually, now I'm sure. However, it's still not working. Should I give it a higher K priority?

Comment: Did you do a `chkconfig --add` after adding the special comments in your script as described in the man page of `chkconfig`?

Comment: Solved: I followed instructions after trying manually and still didn't work. The solution was adding a lock file at start and erasing it at shutdown.